# How to create / modify a MySQL table to only get distinct values

Tags: mysql

I initially had a .csv file, and I imported the data into SQL. It comprises of footballers' data, so each footballer has a football club. Hence, when I create a reference table for the club, it becomes like this, since it reads the football club for each player entry.

```
id      club      big_club
1      Arsenal       1
2      Arsenal       1
3      Arsenal       1 
       ......       
15     Brighton      0 
16     Brighton      0
17     Brighton      0
```

However, I want

```
id      club      big_club
1      Arsenal       1
2      Brighton      0
3      Chelsea       1
4      Everton       0
......
```

and so on. Currently, I'm thinking of 2 options.

1) Load data and filter directly (most preferred)

2) Load data in first, then update table to find the distinct values

I would like assistance in both. Option 2 sounds rather simple but unfortunately, I only know how to do it from a `SELECT DISTINCT standpoint` and not an `UPDATE` standpoint.

For loading data into the table, this is what I have.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/epldata_final.csv'
INTO TABLE big_clubs
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@name, @club, @age, @position, @position_cat, @market_value, @page_views, @fpl_value, 
@fpl_sel, @fpl_points, @region,
@nationality, @new_foreign, @age_cat, @club_id, @big_club, @new_signing) 
SET id=@id, club_id = @club_id, club = @club;
```

I tried `SET club_id = DISTINCT @club_id` but that doesn't work.

Would appreciate help / guidance for both methods.

Comment: Create Table club (id int auto_increment primary key, clubName varchar(20), bigClubID int);

insert into club (clubName,bigClubID) select distinct (club,big_club) from csvLoadedTable;

Comment: sry, but your comment does not answer my question. Please see my 2 options.